# Possible reasons for an incorrect VPN geolocalization

Tags: vpn, geolocation

I have installed a VPN on my computer via OpenVPN and a vpnbook.com French server. When activated, IP sites correctly locate me in France (I am currently on holiday in another European country), yet some websites will still "guess" that I am not actually in France. One specific case is a TV replay website that will tell me that the content is not available in my country.

What could be the reason behind such a guess? How does the target website identify that the traffic coming from a French server is not actually coming from France? Does it have this server identified as "VPN" and thus tagged as "foreign"?

Comment: IP sites only look at the requesting IP. Sites that want to block users from certain areas run checks on the browser itself.

Comment: While the question is closed now, the answers dont cover a likely scenario: The service didn’t geolocate you at all. It just knows that the IP is a known exit node for a VPN and blocks you for that reason.